# strongloop fails to install on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, node.js, strongloop

Experimenting with strongloop.
node version is v0.10.31
visual studio 2013 installed.

npm install fails.

**this path look suspicious:**

```
node "c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
```

---

console:

```
$ npm install -g strongloop
/

> node-syslog@1.1.7 install C:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\node-syslog
> node-gyp rebuild
|
C:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\node-syslog>

   node "c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"


rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
syslog.cc
c:\users\bruce\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\node-syslog\node-syslog.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'syslog.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\node-syslog\build\syslog.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\node-syslog
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.31
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'syslog.h': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

node-syslog is an optional dependency, npm prints errors when it fails to build it, and then continues to install strongloop. Or, that is what npm is supposed to do, and does usually.

Its impossible to know from above whether strongloop actually installed correctly or not.

As for the "suspicious" path, that is npm printing out that it is calling its own internal copy of node-gyp. No idea why it uses the .. and all, you could ask them, but its not a problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention. After install, try to run "slc -v", if it runs, then strongloop was installed successfully.